# Proving Some Relations for Gradient, Curl and Divergence of a Tensor Field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose that $\mathbf{T}$ is a tensor field of order $n\ge1$ and also introduce curvilinear coordinates $q^i$ and the corresponding basis by the relations

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=\chi(\boldsymbol{q}) \\
\mathbf{g}_i&=\frac{\partial\chi}{\partial q^i}
\end{align*}

then one can usually construct a reciprocal basis $\mathbf{g}^i$ having the property

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{g}_i\cdot\mathbf{g}^j=\delta_i^j
\end{align*}

let us make the following definitions for gradient, divergence and curl

\begin{align*}
\text{grad}\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{n}&=\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}+\alpha\mathbf{n})-\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x})}{\alpha} \\
\text{div}\mathbf{T}&=\lim_{|\Omega|\to0}\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\partial\Omega}\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{n}dA \\
\text{curl}\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{n}&=\lim_{|\Gamma|\to0}\frac{1}{|\Gamma|}\int_{\partial\Gamma}\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{t}dL
\end{align*}

then I am interested to prove the following relations

\begin{align*}
\text{grad}\mathbf{T}&=\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial q^i}\otimes \mathbf{g}^i\\
\text{div}\mathbf{T}&=\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial q^i}\cdot\mathbf{g}^i \\
\text{curl}\mathbf{T}&=\mathbf{g}^i\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial q^i}
\end{align*}

where $\otimes,\cdot,\times$ are tensor product, contraction and cross product.

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Most of your questions are answered on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)

Comment: @pluton: Many thanks for providing the link. :)